# how to get the time difference between two ubuntu machines

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time

i need to get the time difference between two Ubuntu Linux machines with little configuration as possible .note this is not network latency.difference of the system clocks up to milliseconds or seconds. detailed steps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know how to set up ssh authentication so that you don't need to enter a password from your user, the following shell command will get you the time difference in seconds. If you want greater precision you can play with the date formatter strings to get the time to nanoseconds.

```
echo $(($(ssh machine1 date +%s) - $(ssh machine2 date +%s)))
```

Of course there is a time lag to execute the two ssh commands. So the resulting time is not super accurate. Which may or may not be adequate for you.

If you want something more accurate you can use ntp if it is set up on your server already or if you are ok to set it up: https://superuser.com/questions/408753/determine-the-time-difference-between-two-linux-servers